# LibreOffice Calc Chart is missing data points. How to force all data points on scatter plot?

Tags: libreoffice

What do I have to do to make LibreOffice put *all* data points in two simple columns named `x` and `y` onto a scatter plot chart?

I'm creating a simple scatter plot chart on LibreOffice 7.0.4.2, but I can't for the life of me get it to display *all* of the data points. It just skips over many of them and refuses to put them on the cart.

### What *does* work

First, let me show you what does work. Here's a very simple table. It has an `x` column. It has a `y` column. It has several rows with `(x,y)` pairs. First, it has a simple line with points at `(1,1)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,3)` and `(4,4)`. Then it has a couple points added to x=1 at `(1,2)` and `(1,3)`. Finally it adds another point to x=2 at `(2,3)`

> **Note** Since there are multiple outputs for the same x-input, this is *not* a function. Therefore, this example demonstrates that LibreOffice Calc should have no issues making a scatter plot of a dataset that is not a function.

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

In LibreOffice, this is pretty simple.

1. Open a new spreadsheet in LibeOffice Calc.
2. Add the above data:

   [image: data in spreadsheet]
3. Select all of the data:

   [image: all data selected]
4. Click *Insert* → *Chart*:

   [image: Insert -> Chart]
5. Choose *Chart Type* = *XY (Scatter)*:

   [image: Chart Type = XY (Scatter)]
6. Admire the wonderful chart that has all 7 data points, as expected:

   [image: chart with all data points shown]

### What *doesn't* work

Now, I try to follow the same process above, but for some *real* data as follows:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.005304 |
| 2 | 0.005314 |
| 3 | 0.005186 |
| 4 | 0.00513 |
| 5 | 0.005135 |
| 6 | 0.00502 |
| 7 | 0.004925 |
| 1 | 0.004654 |
| 2 | 0.004742 |
| 3 | 0.004923 |
| 4 | 0.004623 |
| 5 | 0.004587 |
| 6 | 0.004367 |
| 7 | 0.004262 |

1. Open a new spreadsheet in LibeOffice Calc.
2. Add the above data:

   [image: data in spreadsheet]
3. Select all of the data:

   [image: all data selected]
4. Click *Insert* → *Chart*:

   [image: Insert -> Chart]
5. Choose *Chart Type* = *XY (Scatter)*:

   [image: Chart Type = XY (Scatter)]
6. Get confused because only 2 data points appear. There should be 14.

   [image]
7. Click on *X Axis* and manually adjust it so that all x values are within range of the chart:

   [image: plot showing only 2 points]

   [image: LibreOffice Scale menu for X Axis]
8. Click on *Y Axis* and manually adjust it so that all y values are within range of the chart:

   [image: plot showing only 2 points]

   [image: LibreOffice Scale menu for Y Axis]

   [image: Final Result]

What's wrong? Why won't LibreOffice chart the entire data set??

Comment: I have LibreOffice 7.3.6.2 30(Build:2) with Ubuntu 22.04 and using your data I have no issues at all.  Maybe try upgrading.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with both LibreOffice 7.3.6.2 and 7.0.4.2, but wasn't able to. Both versions create the plots correctly. Can you try to reinstall LO using `sudo apt install --reinstall libreoffice` and see if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Update: I was able to chart all the data points by saving the file to a `csv`, closing LibreOffice, opening the new `.csv`, and then creating the chart. My best-guess is that the data was "not a number". I did try to convert both columns of data to "numbers" following various guides, but the only thing that worked for me was to dump to csv and then open it again.

Comment: Can you also try to copy and paste the numbers as you provided them in your question? This should confirm if it was indeed a number formatting issue.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog That's what I did to solve it :) I copied-and-pasted from this issue on SE into a new LibreOffice spreadsheet, and the issue was not reproducible. I got the data from someone else's CSV, but somehow the problem is invisible to the human eye. Something in the encoded data that cannot be seen visually :(

Comment: I could have a look to see if I can find the exact issue if you could somehow (e.g. via Google Drive) provide the Calc file with the problematic data (just with the data you shared here, no need for the full dataset). You could then have an exact answer about the problem.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog unfortunately I don't have the original file anymore. I did try to reproduce it from the original CSV, but I couldn't. However, I did produce a subset issue: where it takes my x values (that range from 1-7, each appearing twice) and somehow doesn't follow them (the range on the x-axis becomes 1-14). This was shown above too, and I don't know why it happens. Here's the file https://ufile.io/kcj7soen

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the solution for you. Indeed it has to do with the formatting of the cells.

As you can see in your screenshots, the column labeled as `x` is  right-aligned in the data that are plotted correctly, while it's left-aligned, in the problematic data. In LibreOffice Calc, cells formatted as numbers are right-aligned, so that means that the values of your `x` column are not numbers.

You would think (and actually [you have tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433280/libreoffice-calc-chart-is-missing-data-points-how-to-force-all-data-points-on-s?noredirect=1#comment2497030_1433280)) that selecting the data in the `x` column → <kbd>right-click</kbd> → *Format Cells...* → *Number* → *-1235* (or any other number option) would format the data as numbers. But still, the `x` column data would remain left-aligned, meaning they are still not numbers! The reason for this must be that the data were not properly imported to Calc from a text file of some form.

So to convert the `x` column to numeric and solve your issue do the following:

1. Select the data in the `x` column (or the whole column actually) → <kbd>right-click</kbd> → *Format Cells...* → *Number* → *-1235* (or any other number option).
2. With the data selected, go to *Data* on the menu bar → *Text to Columns...* and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

That should work for your data. You should see the numbers in the `x` column right-aligned now and the plot should be updated and correctly show the data.

- Reference: [Ferrangie's answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-convert-a-libreoffice-calc-column-into-number-format/48591/6) to [How do I convert a LibreOffice Calc column into number format?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-i-convert-a-libreoffice-calc-column-into-number-format/48591/3)